# how to use megaparsec's combinators on StateT

Tags: haskell, state, monad-transformers, megaparsec

I'm building a compiler for java for university project, in my project my parsers are mostly `StateT (Scope,SymbolTable) String m a` where `Scope` is the scope we're at now(method,class,etc) and `SymbolTable` holds the symbols defined till now.

I wanted to use megaparsec's combinators on those parsers, for `parens`,`braces` it's not problem, I just use `mapStateT` but for `sepBy` and others I developed this function :

```
mapsequence :: (Monoid s,Monad m) => (m (a,(b,s)) -> m [(a,(b,s))]) -> StateT (b,s) m a -> StateT (b,s) m [a]
mapsequence f stm = do
                      s <- get
                      ases <- lift $ f $ runStateT stm s
                      case ases of
                        (_:_) -> do
                               put ((fst . snd . last) ases,(mconcat . map (snd . snd)) ases)
                               return $ map fst ases
                        [] -> return []
```

Now `f` would be for example :

```
\p -> p `sepBy` semi
```

Anyway I realized lately that the function above is wrong, the function will run the parser(encapsulated in `StateT`) feeding it the state we have right now which is `s` then it will run it again but instead of feeding it the new state resulting from the first run it will feed it `s` again and again and ... .

How do I use megaparsec's combinators like `sepBy`,`sepEndBy` and etc so that I run the parser many times but chaining the resulting state from the first to the second to the third etc ?

Comment: This looks wrong. `runState` should get you `((b, s), a)`, not `[a]`, so that you could `put` that state.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz the state is `(b,s)` so `runState` would return `(a,(b,s))`, I run the function `f` on the result to get `[((b,s),a)]`

Comment: So there's your problem. You're left with multiple states. Which one should you pick now?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz exactly, that's my problem, I have to parse statements which include variable declaration statements, when `int x=3;` occurs `x` should be added to the symboltable but those statements are seperated by a semi colon, that's why I'm asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why I thought that I needed a special function to do this, `sepBy` and others are defined on `Alternative` and because every `StateT` has an `Alternative` instance functions like `sepBy`,`many`, etc can be called directly.

My problem probably was because I had to use `symbol`,`char`,etc which I thought are `ParsecT ...` but then I realized those functions are defined in terms of `MonadParsec` typeclass which `StateT` again has instance for so I didn't even need `lift` or `mapStateT`.

So all I did is to change functions signatures to work with `MonadParsec` and my problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Megaparsec has a monad transformer interface [`ParsecT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec-5.3.0/docs/Text-Megaparsec.html#t:ParsecT):

> ```
> data ParsecT e s m a
> ```
>
> `ParsecT e s m a` is a parser with custom data component of error `e`, stream type `s`, underlying monad `m` and return type `a`.

You should be able to use this with something like `type Parser = ParsecT Dec Text (State (Scope, SymbolTable))`, which will add parsing functionality to the underlying `State (Scope, SymbolTable)` monad.

Comment: all my parsers are `StateT (Scope,SymbolTable) String (ParsecT ...) a` here, I've got a lot of them I can't change them easily , anyway I found the solution and I'm going to post it